# Getting NoClassDefFoundError even tho the system can see the class ist is meant to load

Tags: java, class, urlclassloader

The code block below is inside a function that accesses a jar file.  I have already checked to see if the path to the file is correct.  When printing the classnames from the jar file to the console, i see all the correct classnames.  "model_with_HSQLDB_1_8.HSQLDB_Local_Model_1_8" is among one of those class names.  When i try to load that class using the code below, i get an error.

```
Class myClass = getClassFromJarFile(jarfile, "model_with_HSQLDB_1_8.HSQLDB_Local_Model_1_8");


public static Class getClassFromJarFile(File jarfile, String className){

    try (URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
                 new URL[] { new URL("jar:file:" + jarFile + "!/") })) { 

        return cl.loadClass(className);
    }
}
```

The cl.loadClass() throws the Error.

I get the following error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: interfaces/Modelable_1_8...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: interfaces.Modelable_1_8
```

the weird thing is that the error is `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: interfaces.Modelable_1_8"`
instead of something like `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model_with_HSQLDB_1_8.HSQLDB_Local_Model_1_8"`

Any help on this topic would be great!

Comment: Loading one class might require also loading other classes that it depends on.

Comment: Is there a way that this can be done automatically, or do i have to do that manually from inside the main method?

Comment: It’s automatic, but all of the dependencies need to be available to the class loader (or its parents).

Comment: I checked the project and found that the model_with_HSQLDB class uses the Modelable_1_8 interface and that the problem is probably with that.  

It's also pretty old code (Java 1.8) that i was trying to run on Java 11 or newer.  I've also seen a lot of posts that from Java 1.8 to the later versions quite a few breaking changes occurred.